# Eclipse E4: Awful Eclipse/OSGI core NullPointerException (etc.) that is terminating app on startup

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

Have been regularly RUN-ning a test E4 application (via the Eclipse IDE) without too many problems. However, I have just encountered an error on startup (RUN/DEBUG) that is terminating the application before it starts. It dies before any window is shown. I have NO IDEA why this started happening.

Via DEBUG, the first error (NullPointerException) I come across is in the:

```
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.CharsetDeltaJob class: at line 206 (the Platform. call):

public void startup() {
    Platform.getContentTypeManager().addContentTypeChangeListener(this);
}
```

I also get a slew of error messages in the terminal or log. I can find NO REFERENCE to any of my code. It all seems to be Eclipse core stuff. I'll include them at the end of this message. Questions:

1) Is there any way to make sure the OSGi system completely restarts upon a new DEBUG/RUN call?

2) Is this "deep" of an error common?

3) Any advice for debugging this kind of stuff? I've had some success with Eclipse/E4, but if this level of errors is commonplace, not sure if I'll be able to continue.

The stacktrace:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:320)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:391)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.EcorePlugin.getWorkspaceRoot(EcorePlugin.java:1131)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.<clinit>(ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.java:393)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getURIConverter(ResourceSetImpl.java:499)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:369)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.getResource(ResourceHandler.java:350)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadResource(ResourceHandler.java:326)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadMostRecentModel(ResourceHandler.java:243)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:394)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:248)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:143)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.CharsetDeltaJob.startup(CharsetDeltaJob.java:206)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.CharsetManager.startup(CharsetManager.java:502)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2468)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2219)
at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:463)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
... 39 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.CharsetDeltaJob.startup(CharsetDeltaJob.java:206)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.CharsetManager.startup(CharsetManager.java:502)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2468)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2219)
at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:463)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:320)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:391)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.EcorePlugin.getWorkspaceRoot(EcorePlugin.java:1131)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.<clinit>(ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.java:393)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getURIConverter(ResourceSetImpl.java:499)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:369)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.getResource(ResourceHandler.java:350)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadResource(ResourceHandler.java:326)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadMostRecentModel(ResourceHandler.java:243)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:394)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:248)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:143)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-01-12 00:02:40.687
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.EcorePlugin.getWorkspaceRoot(EcorePlugin.java:1131)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.<clinit>(ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.java:393)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getURIConverter(ResourceSetImpl.java:499)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:369)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.getResource(ResourceHandler.java:350)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadResource(ResourceHandler.java:326)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadMostRecentModel(ResourceHandler.java:243)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:394)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:248)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:143)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (18).
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:320)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:391)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 23 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.CharsetDeltaJob.startup(CharsetDeltaJob.java:206)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.CharsetManager.startup(CharsetManager.java:502)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2468)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2219)
at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:463)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
... 39 more
```

Comment: Is this a pure e4 app (using the Application.e4xmi etc.) or a 3.x compatibility app? You can't use the resources plugin in a pure e4 app.

Comment: As far as I know (long time java, new to Eclipse/E4), it's a "pure" e4 app. I'm using an Application.e4xmi file, and I constructed the application project through the E4 tools add-ons. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @greg449: Just curious: why can't you use the resources plugin in an e4 app?

Comment: Follow up. I just found out that I had:

Comment: Follow up. I just found out that I had 3 of the related plugins checked for inclusion in the application: org.eclipse.core.resources and a couple nearby. The problem: I have never included them myself. I RUN the app -- works fine. I go in and make a change to my code, then poof! I'm getting those errors on the next run. I just deselected those related plugins and NOW THE APP WORKS FINE AGAIN. How/why on earth were those added to the selected Plugins in the first place?

Comment: @s.d Pure e4 applications don't support a lot of the old 3.x code partly to reduce the size of RCPs and to make a fresh start. Including the resources plugin would drag in all the old workspace code.

Comment: See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67959779

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure e4 applications (ones that use the Application.e4xmi) can't use a lot of the old Eclipse 3.x compatibility code. In this case you seem to have included the `org.eclipse.core.resources` plugin (or possibly Eclipse added them automatically by mistake).

When building your RCP using a xxx.product file if you use a 'feature based' build you can just specify the features:

```
<your feature>
org.eclipse.e4.rcp
org.eclipse.emf.common
org.eclipse.emf.core
```

which will ensure that the build only uses e4 plugins.

It is possible to use some other Eclipse plugins, for example:

```
org.eclipse.jface.text
org.eclipse.text
```

basically you have to look at the plugin's dependencies to see if uses plugins that won't work such as `org.eclipse.core.resources` or any `org.eclipse.ui.*` plugin.

Comment: And that's the spooky part: I did NOT add/select them myself. One second I run the app, and all is good. I make some changes to what seems to be innocuous code, then run again, and POOF -- I get a slew of bizarre errors. Methinks there's some faulty magic somewhere under the hood. Oh well. Hope nothing like that happens again. Thx, Greg.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same problem, while building a minimal set of bundles to use the `org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter` Eclipse application. The NPE is caused by `Platform.getContentTypeManager()`, when the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.content.IContentTypeManager` service is unavailable.

Make sure you have the following bundles:

```
osgi.bundles=\
org.apache.felix.scr@2:start,\
org.eclipse.core.runtime@start,\
org.eclipse.core.contenttype
# other bundle dependencies
```

The Apache Felix SCR bundle must start at runlevel 2 so that the Eclipse Content Mechanism can register its service, which is required by the Core Resource Management bundle.

Comment: If you are using a `*.product` file, have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67959779